# How to exclude routes and ReverseRoutes files auto generated using scoverage for play scala framework?

Tags: scala, sbt, scoverage

How to exclude routes and ReverseRoutes files auto generated using scoverage for play scala framework?
My project structure is as follows.

- root

  - modules

    - subModule1
    - subModule2

I tried using following line in root build.sbt but its not working.
ScoverageKeys.coverageExcludedPackages := ";controllers\..*Reverse.*;.*Routes*"

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the routes and ReverseRoutes files auto generated using scoverage for play scala using the following command

```
coverageExcludedPackages := “com.bar.ActorSystem*;com.foo.Boot*”
```

where com.bar and com.foo is nothing but the package path.